# Creating a rsa public key from its modulus and exponent

Tags: openssl, rsa

I want to verify a RSA signature. I have data to verify, the signature and a public key in a form of modulus and exponent. I'd like to do the verification using openssl. Is it possible? I know I can use `openssl rsautl -verify -in sig -inkey key.pem` but I don't know how (using openssl) to create a public key having just it's modulus and exponent.

Maybe other ideas how to check this signature (except writing some programs)?

Comment: "...except writing some programs ..." well if you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) you'd know that's what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: GregS: It's not like that :) I have program which does it but my client claims that is doesn't work properly. So to prove him that he's wrong I want to show that for instance openssl (which he can trust) behaves the same like my program.

Comment: Do you want RSA * structure from a given modulus and exponent?

Answer (score 20):

In order to generate a RSA public key in PEM format to be used with `openssl`, you can follow these steps.

***Create an ASN1 definition file***

Modify the following template to include your modulus and exponent

```
# Start with a SEQUENCE
asn1=SEQUENCE:pubkeyinfo

# pubkeyinfo contains an algorithm identifier and the public key wrapped
# in a BIT STRING
[pubkeyinfo]
algorithm=SEQUENCE:rsa_alg
pubkey=BITWRAP,SEQUENCE:rsapubkey

# algorithm ID for RSA is just an OID and a NULL
[rsa_alg]
algorithm=OID:rsaEncryption
parameter=NULL

# Actual public key: modulus and exponent
[rsapubkey]
n=INTEGER:0x%%MODULUS%%

e=INTEGER:0x%%EXPONENT%%
```

Instead of editing, you also may want to script this using sed

```
sed -i "s/%%MODULUS%%/$(xxd -ps -c 256 mymodulus.bin)/" def.asn1
```

Note the `-c 256` should be chosen according to your key length in bytes.

You can use a similar command for the exponent.

***Generate your RSA key***

Use the following openssl command. This will give you a DER encoded RSA key.

```
openssl asn1parse -genconf def.asn1 -out pubkey.der -noout
```

Then convert it into a PEM key

```
openssl rsa -in pubkey.der -inform der -pubin -out pubkey.pem
```

***Verify using your key***

You can use either `openssl dgst -verify` or `openssl rsautl -verify`

Answer (score -5):

Checking the man pages should give you below

```
 # generate private key
 openssl genrsa > key.priv

 # use it to sign something
 echo "Dirk should be given $10" | openssl rsautl -inkey key.priv -sign > msg.sig

 # create a pub key (modules, exp) from the private key
 openssl rsa -pubout < key.priv > key.pub

 # use that to verify the signature.
 openssl rsautl -in msg.sig -verify -inkey key.pub -pubin
```

all this assuming you want raw keys. If I understand your comment below right - it seems that you do not have modules/exp in a normal format. So you will first have to package it in ASN.1
 in order to use it with the usual tools.

You'll have to write some c/java/etc code for this. An easy way to do this is to use the openssl library; and fill out the RSA * structure.

Comment: I don't see how it solves my problem. I have just two numbers: a modulus and an exponent. And I want to create a file key.pub containing a public key created based on those numbers. Nothing else. I asked this question long time ago and still don't know how to do that.

Comment: Assuming that you do not have the modules and exponent not in the normal BER packaging - you will have to write some ASN.1 packaging to package it thus.